# Send Byte Array

Tags: c#

The pRequest input parameter to the getTEFAuthorization and getPAN methods must be a byte array of the required fields.

I reference a third party Dll that brings the following methods
The getTEFAuthorization method is longer, I use it as an example to see the parameters it receives

```
public object getPAN(ref object pData)
        {
            return getTEFAuthorization(ref pData, 1);
        }


 public object getTEFAuthorization(ref object pData, int pAction)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("**********************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("TEF II .NET v. 1.29.2 2021-05-06");
            Console.WriteLine(Operators.ConcatenateObject((object)"Request:", pData));
            Console.WriteLine("Action :" + Conversions.ToString(pAction));
            bool flag = pAction == 2;
            IDataProvider dataProvider = null;
            ITEFTrxDevice iTEFTrxDevice = null;
            int num = -1;
            string pIdFunction = "";
            ArrayList pDataRequested = null;
            ArrayList arrayList = null;
            PropertyCollection pDataProvided = null;
            string text = null;
            string pPresentationHeader = null ; ......
   }
```

Now instantiate that DLL and call the method

```
TEFTransactionManager TEFT = new TEFTransactionManager();
```

The getPAN method asks for the following

[image]

I create the byte array

```
byte [] OUTPUT_FIELDS_GETPAN = { 40, 41, 80, 42, 53, 81, 82, 83, 84, 91, };
```

tells me the following

[image]

But if I do this it works fine

```
object ejemp = new object();

     TEFT.getPAN(ref ejemp);
```

but how do you assign an array of bytes to that object or what has to be done?

With what parameters or how do you have to fill that getPAN method, how to send that array of bytes that they ask me for?

Comment: Um, `object bytes = OUTPUT_FIELDS_GETPAN; TEST.getPAN(ref bytes);`? (Note that it would *really* help if you'd stick to .NET naming conventions in Stack Overflow examples - the naming here is really distracting.)

Comment: If this dll is meant to be used in C#/Dotnet context, that would really make me wonder. Looking at this code, the first thing I'd say would be: if you want to code in C#, stop thinking in C.